# Unnesting the columns in BigQuery which can have null elements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
with a1 as (
  select 1 as num,
    [1,2] as nested,
    2 as cost
),
a2 as (
  select 2 as num,
  [4,7] as nested,
  2 as cost
),
a3 as (
  select 3 as num,
  [9,8] as nested,
  2 as cost
),
a4 as (
  select 4 as num,
  [4, 6, 8] as nested,
  2 as cost
),
a5 as (
  select 5 as num,
  [19, 11] as nested,
  2 as cost
),
a6 as (
  select 6 as num,
  [] as nested,
  2 as cost
),
table as(
 select * from a1
 union all
 select * from a2
  union all
 select * from a3
  union all
 select * from a4
  union all
 select * from a5
  union all
 select * from a6
) 
select * except(nested)
from table, unnest(nested) as unnested
```

Result generated by the Query

[image]

```
select num, count(unnested) as count, max(cost) as cost_incurred
from table, unnest(nested) as unnested
group by num
```

Result generated by the Query

[image]

Problem with this result is: for num=6, I have no nested columns,
so when I unnest the nested column, it removes the row with num=6 completely, this will create discrepancy when I want to calculate the total cost incurred.

Any help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `left join` instead of `,` (which is a shorthand for `cross join`):

```
select * except(nested)
from table left join unnest(nested) as unnested

select num, count(unnested) as count, max(cost) as cost_incurred
from table left join unnest(nested) as unnested
group by num
```